# Drupal 7 Customize Node Add Form

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

First, let's describe what I have already:

- Vocabulary: "Categories" with some terms added(cat1, cat2, cat3)
- New content type "custom_page" where I added a new field of type "Term reference" using vocabulary "Categories";
- Widget type for previous field is "Check boxes/radio buttons" because a custom_page can be part of multiple categories;

It is possible when adding a new custom_page, to add additional fields for each category selected?

Assuming, I checked "cat1" and "cat3" -> it is possible to add 3 more fields inline (new_field1, new_field2, new_field3) with every category selected?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you want hierarchical taxonomy, or totally custom fields, like text inpute, images etc, taxonomy based? In Drupal there is no mechanism for fields depending on another fields, as far as I know.

Comment: for each category(term from vocabulary) checked I want 3 more fields(simple text fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do with core functionality. You need to modify form using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Probably you would want to use [Drupal form's AJAX](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) to make fields appear.

I don't know if there is a contrib module to do this, I can't see any.